# Does Alia support insert-batch

Tags: clojure, cassandra, cql

[Cassaforte](https://github.com/clojurewerkz/cassaforte) has an insert-batch function for inserting multiple rows into a cassandra CQL 
table in one go.

I've recently switched to [Alia](https://github.com/mpenet/alia) and I'm wondering if it offers the same? I can't see anything immediately in the documentation, and (hayt/values ..) seems to only support a single row insertion at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alia supports CQL batch inserts through the Hayt DSL.

```
(alia/execute
  session    
  (hayt/batch 
    (hayt/queries
      (hayt/insert ...)
      (hayt/insert ...)
      (hayt/insert ...))
```

As per the CQL spec, only DML statements are supported:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html

Comment: To expand on that, cassaforte and alia use the same library under the hood (Hayt), so everything that's doable in CQL with one should be possible with the other. Cassaforte shadows this by aliasing the whole of hayt in a separate namespace.